# Eigen cast with auto return type - Less efficient than explicit return type?

Tags: c++11, eigen

When casting a vector integers (i.e. `Eigen::VectorXi`) to a vector of doubles, and then operating on that vector of doubles, the generated assembly is dramatically different if the return type of the cast is `auto`.

In other words, using:

```
    Eigen::VectorXi int_vec(3);
    int_vec << 1, 2, 3;

    Eigen::VectorXd dbl_vec = int_vec.cast<double>();
```

Compared to:

```
    Eigen::VectorXi int_vec(3);
    int_vec << 1, 2, 3;

    auto dbl_vec = int_vec.cast<double>();
```

Here are two examples on godbolt:

`VectorXd` return type: https://godbolt.org/z/0FLC4r

`auto` return type: https://godbolt.org/z/MGxCaL

What are the ramifications of using `auto` for the return here? I thought it would be more efficient by avoiding a copy, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Eigen's [common pitfalls](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) page covers some issues with using `auto` due to how expressions are evaluated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, in your code in the question you avoid a copy (indeed, until `dbl_vec` is used, it's essentially a `noop`). However, in the code on godbolt, you traverse the original `int_vec`  and evaluate `dbl_vec` at least twice, possibly thrice:

```
max + std::log((dbl_vec.array() - max)
^^^             ^^^^^^^           ^^^
```

I'm not sure if the two calls to `max` are collapsed into a temporary or not. I'd hope so.

In any case, [kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703514/eigen-cast-with-auto-return-type-less-efficient-than-explicit-return-type#comment103703380_58703514) is right and you should [avoid using `auto` with Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html#TopicPitfalls_auto_keyword) unless you know exactly what you're doing. In this case, the `auto` is an expression template that does not get evaluated until used. If you use it more than once, then it gets evaluated more than once. If the evaluation is expensive, then the savings from not using a copy are lost (with interest) to the additional evaluation times.

Comment: The casting within the `dbl_vec` expression is indeed performed twice, but more importantly, this prevents vectorization of the `max + std::log((dbl_vec.array() - max)` expression!